# Multiple ajax requests inside an ajax request using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to nest Ajax requests and return a whole array of results.

I have a first API call and I need to do do other requests according to the first result.

The order is the following:

1. First API call
2. Loop on results and for each result : do API2 call
3. return an array of each element : [{Result1-item, Result2-item})

This is

```
function getVideos () {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'URL1'
    })
        .then(function (list) {
            let videos = [];

            list.videos.function(video) {
                return $.ajax({
                    url: video.url_id
                })
                    .done(function (videoInfo) {
                        videos.push({video: stream, videoInfo: videoInfo})
                    });
            })
        })
        .done(function (allResult) {
            return allResult;
        });
}
```

The calls are doing great but I don't get how to gather the video + video infos in the same array

What is missing ?

Comment: If you need more calls to be returned as array, use [`Promise.all([array of promises])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) `.then(values => { /* here values are an array of responses */})`.

Comment: For nested calls you either need to utilise promises (as above), or have a single callback that's executed when all calls have completed (successful or not).  You can't just `return` values from ajax calls as they're asynchronous.

Comment: What is `list.videos`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Liam I think this question just needs some guidance as OP is already using a promise, prior to their issue.  The comment above about `Promise.all()` is more relevant than that link.